# PHP Regex with conditions

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I defined a log format string like this:

[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% ${$%Context%$}$ $\n$%Extra%\n

Additionally to replacing the %-Keys I want to be able to define conditions like near the %Context%-Key:

So if %Context% is empty, skip the complete ${$%Context%$}$
If %Context% is not empty, also print the prefix { and suffix }

I tried this (I planned to replace the keys within a loop):

```
$output = '';
$subject = '[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% ${$%Context%$}$ $\n$%Extra%\n';
$output .= preg_replace('/(\$(.*|^\$)\$)?%Context%(\$(.*|^\$)\$)?/', '\2test\4', $subject);
```

What I expect (Context empty):

```
[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% $\n$%Extra%\n
```

What I expect (Context not empty):

```
[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% {test} $\n$%Extra%\n
```

What I get (Context not empty):

```
[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% {test}$ $\n%Extra%\n
```

And I don't know where the last $ comes from.

Comment: I tried this in both [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uN9y/) and in php and both times it came back without the $... and without the curly braces in jsFiddle (but that's less relevant I suspect).  My php output from using your code:  `[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% {test} %Extra%\n`

Comment: I'm getting the same result as Ross's [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tB3eQ7)...

`If %Context% is not empty, also print the prefix { and suffix }` => could you please post the expected output in this case...

Comment: That's very strange, I tried with PHP 5.2, and 5.4.. I edited the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution - I use a loop and a if-condition to solve my problem:

```
$output = '';
$subject = '[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% ${$%Context%$}$ $\n$%Extra%\n';
$replace = array('Hello', 'World', '');
$pattern = '/(\${1}([^\$]+)\${1})?%Context%(\${1}([^\$]+)\${1})?/';

foreach ($replace as $r)
{
    if ($r == '')
    {
        $output .= preg_replace($pattern, '', $subject) . '<br>';
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= preg_replace($pattern, '$2' . $r . '$4', $subject) . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% {Hello} $\n$%Extra%\n
[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% {World} $\n$%Extra%\n
[%Time%] %Logger%.%Level%: %Message% $\n$%Extra%\n
```